# Android and FFMpeg. How to add more codecs is build sh script

Tags: android, build, ffmpeg, sh, codec

I built ffmpeg library for my Android project and now I want to add more codecs for my libs. I have build_android.sh script, where are defined encoders-decoders, muxers-demuxers, for example

```
    --enable-decoder=flv \
    --enable-encoder=flv \
    --enable-demuxer=flv \
    --enable-muxer=flv \
```

And I want to add there codecs for bink, avi, smacker and some others. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FFmpeg#Multiverse - here I have found list of codecs.
So, if I need to add for example smacker codec I need to put in my sh script following lines:

```
   --enable-decoder=smackvid \
   --enable-encoder=smackvid \
   --enable-demuxer=smackvid \
   --enable-muxer=smackvid\
```

And the same for all other codecs...
Am I right, or I am wrong? Thank You!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `build_android.sh`, but when configuring FFmpeg you don't need to manually define any decoders, encoders, demuxers, and muxers unless you used a `--disable-foo` option or are using an external library.

Comment: I am sorry for such a late comment. What do you mean by  external library?

Comment: An external library such as libx264, libfdk-aac, libmp3lame, libvorbis, etc. See "External library support" in the output of `./configure --help`.

Comment: So, i need only declare --enable-decoders, --enable-encoders, --enable-muxers, --enable-demuxers? And this is all? Sorry if i am wrong (i know very little about ffmpeg compiling) :-)